# Angular2-Modal won't run in Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular2-modal

I have angular2-modal running fine in my angular 2 app. However, I am having issues testing via Karma. I have set up my test bed with

```
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpModule
            ],
            providers: [
                ApiService,
                MockBackend,
                UiComponentService,
                BaseRequestOptions,
                AlertCenterService,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (backend: any, options: any) => new Http(backend, options),
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                },
                Overlay,
                OverlayRenderer,               
                Modal
            ]
        });
    });
```

However, I get the strange DI Error:

```
Error: No provider for Modal$$1!
Error: DI Error
```

The **UiComponentService** is where I use the modal. Tests were working prior to adding the modal. I can't find a reference to Modal with $$1 appended anywhere, and I don't understand where it is coming from.

Comment: I imagine the Modal is also missing dependencies. I've seen errors like this where only the error only explains the problem with the looked up dependency (the service) and not the dependencies it relies on (even though that's the root cause). How are you configuring it in the main app? Is it just by adding the Modal to the providers, or are you importing some Module.forRoot(). If the latter, you should do the same for the test.

Comment: That did it! I should have asked sooner. Would you mind writing that as an answer? I'd like to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the Modal is also missing dependencies. I've seen errors like this where the error only explains the problem with the looked up dependency (the service) and not the dependencies it relies on (even though that's the root cause). How are you configuring it in the main app? Is it just by adding the Modal to the providers, or are you importing some Module.forRoot(). If the latter, you should do the same for the test

#### *BUT*...

Do you really need to full working `Modal` for a unit test. It might just be better to mock it because all you need to test is the behavior of your service. And I'm assuming all the service does is call some method on the `Modal`. So that's all you really need to test

```
let modal;

beforeEach(() => {
  modal = { openModal: jasmine.createSpy('openModal') }

  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: Modal, useValue: modal }
  ]
})

it('', () => {
  doSomething()

  expect(modal.openModal).toHaveBeenCalledWith(whatever);
})
```

This is just assuming `Modal` has a methed `openModal`. All you really need to test is that service calls the `openModal` method, as that is the behavior of the service being tested.